# C++ ROT13 Function Crashes

Tags: function, visual-c++, rot13

I'm not too good with C++, however; my code compiled, but the function crashes my program, the below is a short sum-up of the code; it's not complete, however the function and call is there.

```
void rot13(char *ret, const char *in);

int main()
{
    char* str;
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Test 1; Does get here!"), _T("Test 1"), MB_OK);
    rot13(str, "uryyb jbeyq!"); // hello world!
    /* Do stuff with char* str; */
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Test 2; Doesn't get here!"), _T("Test 2"), MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

void rot13(char *ret, const char *in){
    for( int i=0; i = sizeof(in); i++ ){
        if(in[i] >= 'a' && in[i] <= 'm'){
            // Crashes Here;
            ret[i] += 13;
        }
        else if(in[i] > 'n' && in[i] <= 'z'){
            // Possibly crashing Here too?
            ret[i] -= 13;
        }
        else if(in[i] > 'A' && in[i] <= 'M'){
            // Possibly crashing Here too?
            ret[i] += 13;
        }
        else if(in[i] > 'N' && in[i] <= 'Z'){
            // Possibly crashing Here too?
            ret[i] -= 13;
        }
    }
}
```

The function gets to "Test 1; Does get Here!" - However it doesn't get to "Test 2; Doesn't get here!"

Thank you in advanced.
-Nick Daniels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` is uninitialised and it is being dereferenced in `rot13`, causing the crash. Allocate memory for `str` before passing to `rot13()` (either on the stack or dynamically):

```
char str[1024] = ""; /* Large enough to hold string and initialised. */
```

The `for` loop inside `rot13()` is also incorrect (infinte loop):

```
for( int i=0; i = sizeof(in); i++ ){
```

change to:

```
for(size_t i = 0, len = strlen(in); i < len; i++ ){
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got several problems:

- You never allocate memory for your output - you never initialise the variable `str`. This is what's causing your crash.
- Your loop condition always evaluates to true (= assigns and returns the assigned value, == tests for equality).
- Your loop condition uses `sizeof(in)` with the intention of getting the size of the input string, but that will actually give you the size of the pointer. Use `strlen` instead.
- Your algorithm increases or decreases the values in the return string by 13. The values you place in the output string are +/- 13 from the initial values in the output string, when they should be based on the input string.
- Your algorithm doesn't handle 'A', 'n' or 'N'.
- Your algorithm doesn't handle any non-alphabetic characters, yet the test string you use contains two.